# Package Installation in R

Tags: r, fft

I am trying to install fftw package in R under Linux. I am using following command:

```
R CMD INSTALL  fftw_1.0-3.tar.gz
```

but geting error:

```
* installing to library â/usr/local/lib64/R/libraryâ
* installing *source* package âfftwâ ...
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for FFTW... configure: error: Package requirements (fftw3) were not met:

No package 'fftw3' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables FFTW_CFLAGS
and FFTW_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.



ERROR: configuration failed for package âfftwâ
* removing â/usr/local/lib64/R/library/fftwâ
```

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850498/how-to-install-the-fftw3-package-of-r-in-ubuntu-12-04 help

Comment: Followed this link but still the problem persist. ANy other idea to get rid of this problem